# Salida extraña de setw para alinear columnas

Tags: c++, c++11

Tengo un problema con setw para alinear unas palabras en concreto, he probado con varias palabras distintas y funciona como se espera, pero con estas palabras en concreto no.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> old_words{"señor","comarca"};
    std::vector<std::string> new_words{"anillos","hobbit"};
    assert(old_words.size() == new_words.size());

    for(size_t i = 0; i < old_words.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << std::setw(45) << std::left << old_words[i] << new_words[i] << '\n';
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

La salida actual del programa es la siguiente:

```
señor                                       anillos
comarca                                      hobbit
```

Y la salida que espereba:

```
señor                                       anillos
comarca                                     hobbit
```

Comment: y cuál es el problema con el código que nos compartes? qué debería hacer y qué hace en realidad?

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

El problema radica en la ñ que ocupa mas de 1byte por eso no está alineado correctamente. Para solucionar el problema basta con sumarle uno al parametro que recibe setw cuando encontremos una ñ.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> old_words{"señor","comarca"};
    std::vector<std::string> new_words{"anillos","hobbit"};
    assert(old_words.size() == new_words.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < old_words.size(); ++i) {

        size_t size_max =  old_words[i].find("ñ") == std::string::npos ? 45 : 46;
        std::cout << std::setw(size_max) << std::left << old_words[i] << new_words[i] << '\n';
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```